# tf.image.random_brightness giving negative values randomly in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

'I am trying image data augmentation in TensorFlow using various methods like rotation, random brightness, random saturation. What I observe that the output of tf.image.random_brightness is not consistent - sometimes it produces negative values. I understand the randomness, but is it correct to produce negative values? When I try to plot the image using matplotlib.pyplot, it fails saying ValueError: Floating point image RGB values must be in the 0..1 range
Below is some sample of the code:'

```
# Function which reads file and converts to image array
def read_images_from_file (input_queue):
    label = input_queue[1]

    file_content = tf.read_file(input_queue[0])
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_content, channels=NUM_CHANNELS)
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32, saturate=True)
    image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH])

.....
    #inside a function which applies various augmentations - code shown only for brightness

    X_init = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=images.shape)
    X = tf.Variable(X_init)

    sess.run(tf.variables_initializer([X]), feed_dict={X_init: images})
    aug_images, aug_labels = (sess.run(tf.map_fn(lambda params: (tf.image.random_brightness(params[0], 0.8, 1), params[1]), (X, labels))))

    #inside a loop after calling above function - output of function is returned to aug_train_images

    print (aug_train_images[i])


'Some sample output:'
    [[[-0.18852733 -0.27872342 -0.31009597]
      [-0.18059228 -0.2786315  -0.3060825 ]
      [-0.1765788  -0.27461803 -0.302069  ]
      ...

      [-0.20366213 -0.19974056 -0.18405429]
      [-0.22792684 -0.22437292 -0.20458125]
      [-0.24324547 -0.23166458 -0.21205674]]
```

'I am using Jupyter notebook with Python 3.5.3 and TensorFlow CPU version 1.5.0-rc0 on Ubuntu 16.10.'

Comment: keras already has image data augmentation builtin. why not use that?

Comment: Thanks Mitch for the suggestion. Right now I am learning TensorFlow and deep learning so trying to limit my code to TF APIs. I feel using high level APIs will be easier and give good results but the learning (i.e. me learning deep learning!)  will be less.

Comment: Also, I could not find method to change the brightness/saturation in Keras's data augmentation library.

Comment: but will changing brightness/saturation actually give a convNet more information to work with? I suspect not.

Answer (score 8):

You are allowing a random change in the intensities (delta) that is between -0.8 and 0.8:

```
tf.image.random_brightness(params[0], 0.8, 1)
```

Note that the images' intensities are in the range [0-1] because you did:

```
image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32, saturate=True)
```

This means that each intensity value *i* in the image will be changed to something between:

```
[i-0.8, i+0.8]
```

which is out of the [0-1] range of an image. In other words, you'll have negative values and values greater than 1.

The first comment is that a delta of 0.8 seems too much (of course it depends on the problem). I'd recommend something around 0.1 (i.e. allow 10% of change).

The second thing, is that you'll have to make sure that after changing the brightness, the image is still an image, that is, clip the intensities to be in the range [0-1]. You can do that by:

```
image = tf.clip_by_value(image, 0.0, 1.0)
```